# Stop audio in Canvas (CreateJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, adobe

Initialized animation:

```
var canvas;
var loaderCanvas;
var stage;

function init(animation, canvas) {

    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
    loader.loadManifest(animation.properties.manifest, true, '{0}/action/animation/'.format(sco.vpScripts));
    loaderCanvas = vmDefferedEvent(loader, "complete");

    function handleComplete(evt) {

        var exportRoot = new animation.create;

        stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
        stage.addChild(exportRoot);
        stage.update();

        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(animation.properties.fps);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    };
};
```

I stop animation using:

```
function stopCanvas() {
    createjs.Ticker.removeEventListener("tick", stage);
};
```

This only stops the animation, but the audio continues to play. How do I stop the audio in animation (animation create on CreateJS)?

Comment: createjs.Sound.stop() - metod to stop audio